# How to use OR operator on three operands?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

Any ideas, or tips (links to tutorials), are much appreciated, I'd be happy to take a reference if this has been addressed elsewhere.

I haven't been able to find anything referencing how to use the OR on three operands here is the question that I got wrong.

Let A = true, B = false, and C = true. Evaluate the following:
(3 != 5) && !(A || B || C)
Response: True
Score: 0 out of 1 No

Is this a trick question?

Comment: `Is this a trick question?` No. Seems like a straight forward logic question.

Comment: What if it said `a + b + c` - how are you supposed to use `+` on three operands?

Comment: @eerorika,@VLAZ, I was distrubuting the not before solving for A || B || C.  In my text book it says you can only act on two operands, so I wasn't sure if the grouping was off.

Comment: And is there anyway I could improve this question so I can get it up voted to at least 0.  I know this is a basic question but I though it being so basic meet the minimum requirements for a good question. Or is there another site that I could use to ask such a simple question.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, evaluate the lefthand operand of `(3 != 5) && !(A || B || C)`.
It is `3 != 5`, which is true.

Then, evaluate the righthand operand of `(3 != 5) && !(A || B || C)`.
It is `!(A || B || C)`.

To evaluate this, let's evaluate the operand of `!` operator, which is `A || B || C`.
`||` operator has left-to-right assosiativity, so `A || B || C` is treated as `(A || B) || C`.

Now `A` is true, so `A || B` is true without seeing the value of `B`. You can say that `A || B || C` is true from this.

`A || B || C` is true, so `!(A || B || C)` is false. Therefore the original expression `(3 != 5) && !(A || B || C)` is false.

Comment: ,@JaMiT, Thank you two I was distributing the ! before I solved A || B || C.

Comment: @jfleck -- it would be okay to distribute the `!` before solving `A||B||C`, but you have to use [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). `!(A||B||C)` is the same as `!A&&!B&&!C`.